# Switching from two-column to one-column document - IEEE class - error

Tags: ieeetran

I am trying to change my two-column IEEE class document to a single column document for revision. Based on other questions on the forum, I have tried the following command:

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofootl]{IEEEtran}
```

However, the following error is returned just before the abstract and after `\maketitle` :

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.457
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, even though I have tried searching online and it pointed to a watermark problem, which I don't think is being used. I do introduce new commands as follows

```
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

And had figures spanning double columns with the `figure*` environment, but have replaced them. Still no joy.

Any help with identifying where the problem is would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a MWE reproducing your problem.

Comment: I have uploaded a snippet of the file (fully functioning) here https://pastebin.com/hNLYKa3j
If you replace line 54 with '\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}', you get the error I have been seeing.